# qtip appears multiple times in fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, qtip2

I have implemented qtip2 in fullcalendar following is the code I have  written to render tooltip

```
eventRender: function (event, element) {
        element.find('.fc-title').append("<br/>" + event.shiftname);
        element.qtip({
            content: {
                text: function (api) {
                    var content = event.description;
                    if (content != '')
                        return content;
                }
            },
            position: { viewport: true },
            style: { classes: 'qtip-custom' },
        });
    }
```

It appears when mouse hover on event. But when I resize the event, qtip appears multiple times.
[image]

Comment: Do you have any other callback functions (like `eventResize`) that could interfere? I cannot reproduce your issue: http://jsfiddle.net/slyvain/fpuppLzy/

Comment: Yes I have a callback function. 'eventResize:eventResized' but I have checked by removing it, the problem remains as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added show: {solo:true} options in qtip

```
            element.qtip({
            content: {
                text: function (api) {
                    var content = event.description;
                    if (content != '')
                        return content;
                }
            },
            position: { viewport: true },
            style: { classes: 'qtip-custom' },
            show: { solo: true }
        });
```

This resolved my issue.